# visual studio 12 windows phone application development

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-7-x64

I am new for windows phone application development. when start a new windows phone application and press ok i get error as 'no windows phone version supported'.
my os is windows 7 and i use visual studio 12. 
- how start a windows phone application in visual studio 12 with windows 7 os.
- how add windows sdk [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDsTU.png)for the visual studio.

[start a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGxyW.png)

Comment: consider vs2017?

Answer (score 0):

Hi at first I also had that problem, you have to upgrade to windows 8, it is not possible to run wp8 on windows 7.
Hope it has helped.